# Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting this error when I try to build my project.

I checked around and saw a similar question but I deleted everything in the bin folder and tried to build the project again but now there are no files in the bin folder no matter what I try.

I did try changing the project from debug to release and I'm still getting the same error

I'm using a computer that has at least 8gb of ram and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Comment: Are you creating an Azure Functions project?  Was the similar question this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246489/azure-function-insufficient-memory-to-continue-the-execution-of-the-program ?